# Vector of classes used in another class

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, array-algorithms

I am creating a cpu scheduling algorithms program and i tried to make a class called process that carries all the attributes of the processes and then i want to make a class for each scheduling algorithms that carry a vector of "process" as a class and start working on this vector in the class functions for example first come first serve algorithm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get your question. What exactly do you need?

Comment: u can use a queue for this but what's your question?